# I want to schedule a batch file without Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, sap-gui, sap-bw

I have to login into SAP BW application via SAP GUI but at specific times and I want that to happen without Windows Task Scheduler. If it's possible to code something within the bat file, then please suggest something. Open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Sadly, this site is not for code requests.

Comment: This question may get better answers if you can explain, in the question itself, why you do not want to use Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: You can create a scheduled task without using the GUI (with a batch command). see ´schtasks /create /?`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want to use task scheduler (since it is the easiest way to schedule your batch file) but you will need at least a 3rd party software as a scheduler and task scheduler happens to be the most convenient one. If it's the case that you don't want any 3rd party software I've seen it once where someone put the batch file in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE with the files that are executed on start. So he just restarted hes server every day and then the batch file was executed on start, but you will need to be creative to find good ways around 3rd party software.